# Como interpretar operadores en Java

Tags: java

Hoy revisando algunas cosas de los operadores me he encontrado con algo así:

```
public class Pruebas {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a=false;
    boolean b=false;
    boolean c=true;

    System.out.println(!a|b&&(c||b)&&c?(a?1:2):3);
  }
}
```

Ejecutándolo arroja `2`

Pues me gustaría saber un poco cómo interpretar la siguiente línea, en qué orden debo hacerlo para entender el por qué eso arroja `2`. Si es posible, contármelo paso por paso.

```
!a|b&&(c||b)&&c?(a?1:2):3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que dividir esa línea en partes:

- Parte 1: `!a|b&&(c||b)&&c`
- Parte 2: `(?a?1:2):3`

### Análisis de Parte 1:

Primero se ejecutan los operadores con precedencia, el cual en este caso es la negación !. La expresión se puede sobre escribir así:

```
(!a) | b && (c||b) && c
```

Ahora, queda evaluar directamente la expresión. Para ello, conviene reemplazar los valores booleanos por las variables, de manera que tienes lo siguiente:

```
(!false) | false && (true || false) && true
```

Resolvemos los elementos en paréntesis primero, y se obtiene:

```
true | false && true && true
```

Ejecutamos uno a uno los operadores. El resultado de `true | false` es `false`:

```
true && true && true
```

Al quedar solo operadores `&&`, el resultado de esta expresión será `true`.

### Análisis de Parte 2:

Una vez que tenemos el resultado de la parte 1, es más sencillo evaluar la parte 2. Reemplazamos las variables por sus valores:

```
true ? (false ? 1 : 2) : 3
```

El operador ternario `?` es como un `if`, por lo que el código podría entenderse como esto:

```
if (true) {
    if (false) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
} else {
    return 3;
}
```

Al seguir la ejecución de este código, se puede ver que el resultado es 2.

Answer (score 1):

Primero revisemos la definición de los operadores:

**!, Negación lógica.**
Se utiliza para invertir el estado lógico de su operando.

editando...()

Tenemos también un **Operador ternario `? :`** , también conocido por operador condicional.

Operador ternario tiene tres operandos y comúnmente es usado para evaluar expresiones booleanas. El objetivo de este operador es decidir qué valor se asigna a la variable. Ejemplo:

```
variable a = (expresión a evaluar) ? valor si es verdadero. : valor si es falso.
```

Teniendo como valores iniciales,

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = false;
boolean c = true;
```

vamos a realizar la evaluación por partes

```
!a|b => true
c||b => true
a?1:2 => 2
```

Reduciendo la sentencia original `!a|b&&(c||b)&&c?(a?1:2):3` tenemos:

```
  true&&true&&c?(2):3
```

por lo tanto evaluando `true&&true&&c` tenemos:

```
true&&true&&true
```

Que al ser evaluada esta expresión tenemos

```
true&&true&&true => true
```

Al final únicamente nos queda la operación ternaria `true?(2):3` que tiene como resultado:

```
true?(2):3 => 2
```